# parse string from soap and fetch data, c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an issue parsing through some XML in C#.

My XML is this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetArticleByIDResponse xmlns="namespace_1">
    <GetArticleByIDResult xmlns:a="namespace_a" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:ArticleHeader>Header text here</a:ArticleHeader>
    <a:Content>Content here</a:Content>
    </GetArticleByIDResult>
    </GetArticleByIDResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

How Can I get the content and article header from that XML when parsed as in as a string. I have tried so many examples, and failed all of them.

It doesnt matter if its linq or XmlDocument. Just need a scenario, where I can grab the content and actually use it.

Comment: if i remember correctly there is a problem with the .NET Soap Parser and you have to put the Namespace on every element i seem to have had this problem when using php to send info to a ASPX Soap Server

Comment: The easiest thing would be to parse the XML string into an actual XML Document.

Comment: Hi David, I would prefer if that wasnt necesary. document.LoadXml should do that trick, no?

@Martin, I have tried adding namespaces and so , but my knowledge within c# is kinda limited, perhaps I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LINQ-to-XML :

```
XNamespace a = "namespace_a";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("your xml string here");
var header = (string)doc.Root.Descendants(a + "ArticleHeader").FirstOrDefault();
var content = (string)doc.Root.Descendants(a + "Content").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I completely spaced. I had tried that and other combinations of this. However firebug was not kind to me here. Was not the same output as in the source code:(
A few hours wasted there. TY for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment the .Net Soap System is bugged or just flaming wrong as it does not support using xmlns as a namcespace for some stupid reason i have spent many hours with this problem from a php client to a .Net Server to correct try this.

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Body xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <GetArticleByIDResponse xmlns="namespace_1">
      <GetArticleByIDResult>
        <ArticleHeader xmlns="namespace_a">Header text here</ArticleHeader>
        <Content xmlns="namespace_a">Content here</Content>
      </GetArticleByIDResult>
    </GetArticleByIDResponse>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

i think that should work for if you should be using php to send to soap i have a fix on a feature/bug request with php https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64704&edit=3 that will correct the problem with php if your using another soap client request builder you will need to see if you can tell it to use in-line namespacing insted of named/taged namespacing (i think thats what they call it but i cant be certain)

Comment: Its in c# though, not php:) If it only was in php...WOuld be easier for me then

Comment: the error is in .NET i just found it from php. PHP only uses named/taged namespacing so i had to convert it to inline as some one commented try using a DOM module or XML Parser and just run it as XML.

The other one you can check is that the Content/Header do they have any special chars if so make sure the're in CDATA wrappers

Comment: Hi @Martin,

I have tried with XML parsing. 

IE:

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(responseFromServer);  

And ....  then I fail everytime when I actually try to get the data I need - such as ArticleHeader. Most likely because my c# isnt very good.

Comment: Have you checked response from server contains valid XML? including the XML header?